# Pushing files from AWS EC2 instance to gitlab repo

Tags: amazon-ec2, devops, gitlab-ci

I deployed a DDoS honeypot called Amppot in a ubuntu EC2 machine to study characteristics of attacks. This honeypot automatically outputs daily logs and sqlite files describing the requests it got.

I wrote a python script that converts the sqlite file into csv file and does some treatments.

My workflow at the moment is:

1. I connect to the instance via ssh
2. I  copy the sqlite files from the ec2 instace to my machine
3. I execute the python script on my machine
4. I push the csv files produced by the script to a gitlab repository so that all members have the data.

I would like to automate all of this using a gitlab CI/CD pipeline.
All the information I found on google are about tasks going in the opposite direction (from local to ec2 instance).

I managed to add a bash runner to the gitlab project and I know that I have to write the .gitlab-ci.yml file. I also know that I will probably need to setup a service account. However, I have never used gitlab CI/CD or done any DevOps before so I don't know if what I want to do is even possible.

Comment: can you elaborate on why do you need to "bring sqlite files" onto your ec2 instance?

Comment: I have edited my question: I meant that I copy the files from the ec2 instance to my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you are leveraging Gitlab (for storing logs, metrics, app data, etc.) in the wrong way. Source control management (SCM) systems are meant for your source-code, and clearly not for application logs or any data your app is producing.

Instead, for this you would use tools like e.g. CloudWatch logs, S3, any other data source (ElasticSearch, DynamoDB, RDS, etc.). So your application (Amppot) should be instrumented accordingly.

If you pick CloudWatch for logs and metrics collection, you could configure Amazon CloudWatch agent on your EC2 instance and instrument it to push your logs (that your application is producing) to a CloudWatch log group. See documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

Your app would push its `stderr` and `stdout` streams into local files (e.g. `/var/log/amppot.log`), and CloudWatch agent would sync them with AWS CloudWatch service.

If, despite of the above, you still want to push your application files to Gitlab (from your EC2), then simply configure a cron job, that will execute the following bash script on a regular interval:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/user/my-git/repo
git add /home/user/amppot.log
git add /home/user/amppot.sqlite
git commit -m "commit message $(date +'%s')"
git push origin master
```

You might want to communicate with Gitlab via ssh, so run `ssh-keygen` to generate an ssh keypair and then copy its public part (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to GitLab.

Another option would be to package your app in a Docker image and then run it using Elastic Container Service (ECS). The good thing is you don't need to write `stderr` and `stdout` streams into files, because ECS will collect them and stream directly to CloudWatch for you. The downside of this approach is you have to study `Docker` and `ECS`, store your Docker images in a registry (`ECR`), configure ECS cluster, etc. This is obviously some extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

if the csv report is generated in the gitlab-ci job you can just persist it as a job artifact.

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

it can also be published to the gitlab pages part of that repository

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/index.html (see examples. basically it is 2 lines on the gitlab jobs where you save the artifact/report)